# how to summarize total hours worked by an employee per week based on the schedule

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with 3 sheets. The second sheet is a list of permutation/combination of employee and the possible shifts they can work and hours they get.

[image]

The first sheet has a monthly calendar view. For each calendar day they are select from the list from second sheet
[image]

I want the their sheet to display number of total hours each employee is scheduled to worked based on sheet 2 numbers ( column B)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome scheduler ... I made one just like it a couple of years ago but will additional reporting pages that would break down the total hours by standard pay, OT pay, and holiday pay, then with that information calculate their gross pay.

I recreated a basic version of what you have pictured above and then put together two different methods for calculating the total hours per week per employee based on the schedule.

The first way is the simpler way that makes each calculation individually and then totals them on the back end.  To do so you will use the 'countif' function for each shift for each person (the range is the whole calendar and the , then multiply by the corresponding number of hours per shift on the 2nd page.
Then in the next column you see I merged the cells next these subtotals, and wrote a 'sum' formula to total the subtotals for each shift totals in column J.  This approach is easier to put together and easier to diagnose issues with as you are working on it.

[image: Just imagine that the section on the left and right are on different pages]

The 2nd method I used is more complicated as it nests these functions into a single operation using the 'sum' and then several iterations of the 'countif' within it.

[image]

If you really want to get fancy you could go another step further and put together an array formula, but they are a bit more tricky.

Depending on how meticulous you are about having innocuous data, I added an additional condition on mine that would leave the totals cells blank if someone didn't work, just because I don't like to see the '0' when I was reviewing the back end report.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the response. This is very helpful. Would you be able to share your excel sheet that you had created couple years back?

Comment: I looked for the original file in my archives drive but I didn't see it, I did however find a time sheet that I made with just the hourly calculations, without the calendar style scheduling page that I made for another company just last year and have made a few versions of with different breakdown based on someone industry, if you would like it you are welcome to it.